# Interpreting random forest in pySpark

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-ml

Good evening people,

I am trying to find a way of interpreting a random forest in Spark. By interpreting i mean finding out which variables were the most influential in the **specific** row.

With python, i used to do this:

```
from treeinterpreter import treeinterpreter as ti
prediction, bias, contributions = ti.predict(rfc, X)
```

The econtributions array had all the information i needed and then i could manipulate it to get the desired outcome. Is there a way to do this with spark in python?

Comment: Did you try to use model.toDebugString() and MulticlassMetrics?

Comment: Hmm, maybe i havent explained my problem correctly? These things dont seem to do what i am trying to achieve here. 

I care about taking the contributions(aka how much variance) each variable introduces to a predictive outcome.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are talking about features importance. 
Implementation in pyspark.ml when you are working with Pipeline object:

```
tree = model.stages[-1]
# load feature importance from the model object
print(tree.featureImportances)

# You can also print the trees with nodes: 
print('Trees with Nodes: {}'.format(tree.toDebugString))
```

Or when you are working in pyspark.ml without pipeline:

```
from pyspark.ml.classification import RandomForestClassifier
rf = RandomForestClassifier()
model = rf.fit(data)
print(model.featureImportances)
```